# Vertically aligning image and span inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, line-height

I have an image and a span in a button, and I've tried using:

1. flex with align-items: center
2. setting span line-height to same height as container
3. inline-block and vertical-align

but if I don't add a 1px padding-top to the image, it doesn't appear to be truly vertically aligned in the div, while the span text looks fine, and I can't figure out why.

HTML

```
   <button class="metabolite-btn">
      <img src="/images/metabolite/icon_question.svg" class="metabolite-btn__image">
      <span class="metabolite-btn__text">代謝物質とは</span>
   </button>
```

CSS

```
  .main-wrapper {
    .metabolite-btn {
      width: $vw-size-115-width-375;
      border-radius: 14px;
      border: none;
      height: 28px;
      background-color: $main-color;
      padding: 0 0 0 5px;
      text-align: left;
      cursor: pointer;

      &__image {
        width: $vw-size-20-width-375;
        padding: 1px 0 0 0;
      }

      &__text {
        font-size: $vw-size-12-width-375;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: $white;
        line-height: 28px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To align both the elements vertically, you need to add `display:flex` and `align-items: center` to parent which is your button (Shown below)

```
//CSS
button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/kjaq165h/5/)